# crash in webview (-[__NSCFConstantString runActionForKey:object:arguments:])

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I created project in xcode 5 and now i opened that project in new xcode 6.0.1.every thing work fine but if i load any url in uiwebview. App is crashing and it showed the following error.

```
-[__NSCFConstantString runActionForKey:object:arguments:]:
```

and this is my code:

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, IS_WIDESCREEN ? 568.0-44.0 : 480.0-44.0)];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.apple.com/" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
   [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Also i tried by creating new project and copy pasted all files in that, still in new project also its crashing

Could any one knows why it is crashing like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because you or someone else is sending a method runActionForKey:object:arguments: not to an object that can handle that method, but to an NSString*.

Look at the stack trace where exactly the method is called. Figure out what object it is sent to. Figure out why that object is an NSString. Fix the problem.

Comment: I tried by adding only webview to window and commented all other code still its crashing and showing same error.

Comment: runActionForKey:object:arguments: method is not local method it's a method of CAAction class.